# Timeout for QueryRow method call using the database/sql package in Golang

Tags: go

What is the appropriate way to implement a timeout for a `QueryRow` method call using the `database/sql` package in Golang? There have been a lot of discussion about this topic and I like to know if there is a solution/best practice in golang 1.7 other than using the `context` package like described here:

[Ability to timeout when wating for the connection from the pool](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13327)

Further, it seems that the [context support](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15123) has been [implemented recently](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/e13df02e5fbf2c0cd8811b826a8c8567efa882dd). What would be the appropriate way to use the context to timeout connections?

Answer (score 6):

As far as go 1.7, you will have to implement your own functionality at the following levels:

- pool level (question link)
- query level, have to implement your own
  `Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)`
- Database level set the query timeout using transactions, i.e. in SQL Server, one may use `EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 10`. This design though faults its need for more round trips to the server.

I would suggest to switch to at least go 1.8, most database operations now have a context alternative, many changes can be found at this write [up](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F778e7ZSNiSmbju3jsEWzShcb8lIO4kDyfKDNm4PNd8/edit)

**Example**:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "time"

    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/sqlite"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "/tmp/gorm.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Microsecond*10)
    defer cancel()
    res := db.QueryRowContext(ctx, "select id from orders")
    id := -1
    if err := res.Scan(&id); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Print(id)
}
```

**Output**:

```
2018/06/18 19:19:03 interrupted
panic: interrupted

goroutine 1 [running]:
log.Panic(0xc420053f48, 0x1, 0x1)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.10.1/libexec/src/log/log.go:326 +0xc0
main.main()
        /tmp/main.go:23 +0x226
exit status 2
```